# Can a function be big Oh and big theta of another function?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to understand if a function $f(n)$ can be both $O(g(n))$ and $\Theta(g(n))$.

Answer (score 2):

For any function $g$ holds $g\in O(g), g\in \Theta(g),g\in \Omega(g)$.